# Ext over the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[D_{2n}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $D_{2n}$ be the dihedral group of order $2n$ ($n$ odd) generated by $x,y$ with $x^n = y^2 =1.$ Let $H = \langle xy\rangle$. Now we can see that $D_{2n}$ acts on $D_{2n}/H$ and the action is $x.k = k+1$ and $y.k = 2n -(k+1)$, where $k \in D_{2n}/H =\{0,1,2,\ldots,(n-1)\}.$ Hence The group ring $\mathbb{Z}[D_{2n}/H]$ is a module over $\mathbb{Z}[D_{2n}]$. Let $M$ be another $\mathbb{Z}[D_{2n}]-$module with $M$ has only $m$ torsion and $\gcd(m,n) = 1.$

Question : What is $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}[D_{2n}]}^{k}(\mathbb{Z}[D_{2n}/H]; M)$ ? For all $k$.

Guess : All Ext are zero. But I don't have any proof.

Any help(hint, solution or reference) will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: yes. I'm sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Could you upvote and accept the good answers you got on M.SE? It is not that hard, just a click. (Btw, this is the right way to thank on this site.)

Comment: I have deleted my answer, as it contained a flaw I could not fix.